# PHP Разместить изображения на A4

Tags: php, изображения

Есть изображения одного размера в .png
Как можно по средствам PHP реализовать  размещение этих изображений на нескольких A4?

При этом, **на один лист A4 должно помещаться не более 4 изображений**, полученный результат должен отдаваться пользователю в любом формате: (.png, .jpg, .pdf)

Пример: **Пользователь выбрал 5 изображений**, значит **должен получить на выходе 2 листа A4** с этими изображениями: 
На первом будет 4 изображения, а на втором 1 (в углу).

Буду рад любым советам!

Comment: ну тут без библиотек никак. Собираете изображения по 4 в одно изображение и отдаёте файл на скачивание. в этом поможет GD. Чтобы сформировать pdf нужен например DomPDF или аналоги. Задача нетривиальная

Comment: все просто пишите `echo <img src='test1.png'/><img src='test2.png'/>`  и т.д. после ctl+p